# Difference between subprocess Popen/call/check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

Hi everyone can anyone elaborate on the difference between

```
subprocess.Popen
subprocess.call
subprocess.check_output
```

and also if possible then please explain difference between
`x.readlines()` versus `x.communicate()`?

i.e difference between

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
ls = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
**out = ls.stdout.readlines()**
print out
```

and

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
ls = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = ls.communicate()
print out
```

Comment: thanks for editing post.. i not able to found a way to edit POST

Comment: There is an edit link on the bottom left of your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`call` and `check_output` (along with `check_call`) are just utility functions which call `Popen` under the hood.

- `call` returns the exit code of child process
- `check_call` raises `CalledProcessError` error if exit code was non zero
- `check_output` same as above but also returns output.

The difference between `readlines` and `communicate` is that `readlines` is simply a function made on the buffer (`stdout`) while communicate is a method of process class so it can handle different exceptions, you can pass input in it, and it waits for the process to finish.

[Read more here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Thanks for such explanation, one last thing can check_output be used with stdin?

Comment: is there a way to get the check_output return line by line? it seems to wait however long the entire process needs to get the full output, rather than each print() one by one